# ¿Cómo se utilizan los tags en Git?

Tags: git, git-push

Necesito si me pueden ayudar con Tags y Git.

Sé cómo crear un tag y cómo subirlo al servidor por medio de `git push tagname`. Sin embargo, no termino de comprender la lógica de cómo se asocia un commit a un tag.

¿Qué pasos debo seguir?

¿Primero hago el commit, luego el push, luego creo el tag y luego hago push del tag?

Necesito que lo que subí o suba en mi *commit* este asociado a un tag.

```
git add .
git commit -m "nombre del commit"
git push
git tag v1.3
git push v1.3
```

¿Es correcto este orden o se debe crear primero el tag?

Comment: cuando haces el git tag debes decirle a que commit representa `git tag -a v1.3 tuCommit` luego lo debes subir `git push --tags origin tu_rama`

Comment: Yo lo hafo en el mismo order que indicaste, pero al `git tag v1.3` le agrego esto `git tag v1.3 -m "unstring"`

Answer (score 3):

Considera los tag como referencias a commits.

Un commit puede existir (o no) en tu repositorio local o en cualquiera de tus repositorios remotos.

Dicho esto, la única limitación es que tienes es no poder asociar un tag a un commit que no existe.

Puedes hacer commit, crear el tag, hacer push del commit y hacer push del tag.
Puedes hacer commit, hacer push del commit, crear el tag y hacer push del tag.

No puedes crear el tag de un commit que no existe.
Puedes hacer un commit y un tag, pero si quieres subir el tag deberán antes hacer push del commit pues de lo contrario no habría referencia en el repositorio remoto hacia un commit que no ha sido subido.

Espero que te ayude.